# how to avoid that a class gets unloaded during lifecycle

Tags: android, class

I would like to use a class and its class variables as a global "cache" for my globally used variables.

I need to ensure that it never gets unloaded during the app livecycle and loses its values.

**How can I ensure that the class never gets unloaded?**

This is how the class is declared:

```
public class GlobalVars {
    public static Integer gi1;
    public static WebiDBAdapter gDBAdapter;
    }
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Application class

> Base class for those who need to maintain global application state. You can provide your own implementation by specifying its name in your AndroidManifest.xml's  tag, which will cause that class to be instantiated for you when the process for your application/package is created.

---

```
public class ApplicationGlobalVars extends Application 
{     

     public Integer gi1;
     public WebiDBAdapter gDBAdapter;

     // put some setter and getters here. 
     public Integer getGi1()
     { return gi1; } 

}
```

To use it in your activities :

```
ApplicationGlobalVars appState = ((ApplicationGlobalVars)this.getApplication());
appState.getGi1();
```

Comment: as I just commented on a related question - is it really 100% ensured that the class doesn't get killed when the app goes into the background and returns having lost all its values? I read somewhere here that this can happen...

Comment: There is no 100% guarantee  that your application won't be killed once it goes in the background. All you can do is handle these scenarios gracefully

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store global objects that can be accessed by ANY client, you should look into using Application State. For example, application state is often used to implement a global counter that tracks how many times an operation has been performed by ALL the application's clients.

If, however, you need to store separate global state for each client, then Session State would be your best choice.